# Stripes: can't add to form dynamically created tables by javascript

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, stripes

I am creating table dynamically by javascript like this:

```
function createNewML(id, mlName, mlAddress){
    var table = $("<tr />");
    table.html(addToMLContainer(id, mlName, mlAddress));
    $("#AddedMlsContainer").append(table);
}

function addToMLContainer(id, mlName, mlAddress){
    return '<td><stripes:text>' + mlName + ' ' + mlAddress + '</stripes:text></td>' +
            '<td hidden="hidden"><input name="mlFullName" type="hidden" value="' + mlName + ' ' + mlAddress + '" /></td>' +
            '<td hidden="hidden"><input name="mlId" type="hidden" value="' + id + '" /></td>' +
            '<td><input type="button" value="Remove" class="remove" onclick="this.closest(\'tr\').remove()"/></td>'
}
```

Here is my form in jsp file

```
<s:form beanclass="gocardmanager.action.ContentActionBean">

            <div id="added_mls" style="float:left;">
                <table id="AddedMlsContainer" style="width:300px;table-layout: fixed">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Выбранные точки</th>
                        <th>Удалить</th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>



            <div id="added_cards" style="float:left;">
                <table id="TextBoxContainer" style="width:300px;table-layout: fixed">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Card Name</th>
                        <th>Percent</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </div>

            <div id="new_offer_details" style="float:left;">
                <p>Имя</p>
                <input width="200px">
                <p>Описание</p>
                <textarea rows="10" cols="45"  name="text"></textarea>
                <p>Начало</p>
                <p>Окончание</p>
                <p>Загруженная картина</p>

                <s:submit name="test" value="Save Changes"/>

            </div>

        </s:form>
```

And now I want to pass by form all my values from table and other inputs. But I can't get values from my dynamically created table(AddedMlsContainer).

Answer (score 1):

You need to call createNewML() function on document ready to create tables rows. for example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 createNewML('1','testname1','testadd1');
 createNewML('2','testname2','testadd2');
 createNewML('3','testname3','testadd3');
})
```

Comment: @sj_8 this is perfect answer now check to demo http://jsfiddle.net/rohitmalikazad/b7yomjd0/

Comment: @RohitAzad I already created dynamic fields. But I can't pass all values to ActionBean by FORM

Comment: i think same thing you can find from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16316207/binding-dynamic-text-fields-created-by-javascript-to-bean